# How to print joins table data in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm new with CakePHP 3.0.

I have applied a join function to the query builder in articles controller, and the query is working fine but data from the join table is not being displayed.  please help me.

How to display **category_name** field value?
here is my code,
ArticlesController.php

```
public function index() {
        $articles = $this->Articles->find('all')->select(['c.category_name'])
        ->select($this->Articles)
        ->join([
        'table' => 'category',
        'alias' => 'c',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => 'c.id = articles.category_id',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set unique aliases for c.category_name which doesn't match to other fields of Articles

```
$this->Articles->find('all')->select(['category_name'=>'c.category_name'])
 ................

foreach ($articles as $article){
  echo $article->category_name;
}
```